# find and grep pipeline returning nothing

Tags: grep, find

I have files named `lect1.txt`, `lect2.doc`, and `lect3.doc`.

I want to get a file which is a `.txt` file, and contains `lect` as the filename.

I tried

```
find *.txt | grep lect*
```

and it returned nothing.

but when I did

```
find *.txt | grep "lect*"
```

it returned `lect1.txt`.

What's the difference between these two expressions?

Comment: Use `find . -name "*lect*.txt"` ;)

Comment: @A.B. I think I know that solution, but I'm curious about the apostrophe making changes to the result. Why is it necessary? I wrote those file names inside a single file, and used grep lect* filename, and it worked. Is it something with the standard output?

Comment: Yes, the quotes change the meaning. Outside the quotes, the `*` is interpreted by the shell. It's therefore expanded to: lect1.txt lect2.doc lect3.doc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep` searches for the first argument (the pattern) in the files passed on the command line **or** `stdin` if no files are passed.

Without the quote your shell will expand `lect*` to all the files in the directory that begin with `lect`.  Your command will then be:

```
grep lect1.txt lect2.doc lect3.doc
```

which means *search for the text `lect1.txt` in both `.doc` files*.  Unless one of the `.doc` file has the phrase `lect1.txt` within it, it will return nothing. To be more precise, it will look for `lect1` followed by any character (the `.`) followed by `txt`, so it would also find `lect1-txt` and `lect1xtxt` etc)

In your second example, you've quoted `"lect.*"` so that the shell doesn't expand it and it is passed as is to `grep`.  With only a pattern passed as an argument, `grep` will search the filenames passed in `stdin` for the pattern, which is what you are after I believe.

Answer (score 1):

> `find *.txt | grep lect*`

You generally want to give a path name as the first argument to `find(1)`, rather than a file name. It certainly is not a file name pattern. The shell is expanding `*.txt` into the name of all `*.txt` files in the current directory before calling `find`, which isn't what you want here.

More useful variants of that command are

```
find . -name 'lect*' | grep 'txt$'
```

or

```
find . -name 'lect*txt'
```

Also, note that `find(1)` uses [glob expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) in `-name` primaries, whereas `grep(1)` uses [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). That's important here because `*` means something a bit different in the two systems.

BSD and GNU implementations of `find` have the nonstandard `-regex` primary, which lets you use regular expressions instead:

```
find . -regex '.*/lect.*txt'
```

Note that the pattern must match the *whole* path found by `find`, which is why we need the `.*/` prefix, and it isn't necessary to pin the `txt` to the end with `$` as with `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing `find` and it's working accidentally. You see - by running:

```
find *.txt
```

What you're *actually* doing is invoking:

```
find lect1.txt
```

And you're accomplishing little more than `echo`. If however, you run find with a search criteria - so for example:

```
find . -name '*.txt'
```

Then it will traverse the current directory `.` and print any filename matching the specification in any subdirectory.

Care should be taken though, because the '*' as interpreted by find, the `*` in the shell and the `*` in a regular regular expression differ in meaning.

If you're `grep`ing `*` means 'zero or more instances of the preceding character.

So you're actually:

- echoing all your filenames (globbing `*.txt`).
- grepping to print any that match any characters with `lec`, `lect`, `lectt`, `lecttttttt` etc. in the middle.

In your first example though, you grep isn't even getting that far - the *shell* is expanding your pattern, so it's actually grepping for anything that matches `echo lect*` - that may work accidentally, because you have a file in your directory that expands appropriately, but it isn't doing what you intended.

I would suggest instead what you want is:

```
find . -name 'lect*.txt' -print
```

Comment: `*.txt` is unlikely to contain `lect2.doc` in its expansion ;-).